aiohttp: Ignore "Data after `Connection: close`" error
In a domotic context, I'm trying to interact with the Python aiohttp library with a device that has a buggy HTTP server. On some of its endpoints, this HTTP server returns a Connection: close header before the data :

curl -vvvv http://192.168.8.204/getminiteur?dimmer
*   Trying 192.168.8.204:80...
* Connected to 192.168.8.204 (192.168.8.204) port 80 (#0)
> GET /getminiteur?dimmer HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.8.204
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 150
< Content-Type: application/json
< Connection: close
< Accept-Ranges: none
< 
* Excess found in a read: excess = 134, size = 150, maxdownload = 150, bytecount = 0
* Closing connection 0
{"heure_demarrage":"06:15","heure_arret":"06:45","temperature":45,"heure":2,"minute":14,"seuil_start":0,"seuil_stop":0,"seuil_temp":0,"puissance":100}

This header seems to trigger the Data after Connection: close error of the aiohttp library. Is there a way to tell aiohttp to ignore this header since I won't be able to fix the HTTP server?
Firefox, Chrome, or curl have no problem requesting these endpoints, so I assume that I should be able to do the same thing with aiohttp.
Edit: Thanks to Sam Bull's comment, I understood that my problem is not related to the Connection: close header, but rather to the fact that the HTTP server is sending me two concatenated HTTP responses.
With curl, this results in a warning that is only visible with the -v parameter: Excess found in a read: excess = 134, size = 150, maxdownload = 150, bytecount = 0, and in the end, I retrieve the data from the first response (which is the one I'm interested in). The same happens with Firefox or Chrome; they return the data from the first response only.
I have made a network capture of the request and a demonstrator.
I have also noted that with a version lower than or equal to 3.8.5 of aiohttp, I do not encounter any errors and I successfully retrieve my data. Starting from version 3.8.6, I get an exception and I do not see how to retrieve my data.

If the data is accessible with a browser, then please open a bug report with a reproducer and we'll take a look and verify what's happening. That error means that the server has sent a complete message, and then has tried to send another message when the connection is supposed to be closed. Any data in the same message as the close header would still be readable, this is normal HTTP (i.e. header indicates that the connection should be closed once the current response is complete, thus disabling keep-alive).

You also say that curl has no problem, but then show a curl output which appears to be displaying an error message...?

@SamBull : Indeed, you were right. I have added a comment with what I was able to observe with your help. Clearly, the problem here is my HTTP server, which is really buggy. However, it would be good if the aiohttp library adopted what seems to be the traditional behavior, which is to return the data from the first response, as was the case in versions 3.8.5 and earlier. If you think it is relevant, I can indeed create an issue about this.

That specific behaviour comes from llhttp: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/8087

@SamBull : and what you think to add a parameter/option to permit to make aiohttp to adopt the "traditional" behavior ? I finally find a way to fix my issue on the remote device, but, in my previous situation, I was clearly stuck between a buggy device and a behavior of aiohttp that prevented me from overcoming this issue, while with any other tool, I could retrieve the relevant data in my case. I understand the desire to have a default behavior identical to llhttp, but perhaps adding an option to control this behavior would be interesting?

I don't think you understand. You are using llhttp by default. Unless you change the behaviour in llhttp you won't see a difference. We don't recommend disabling llhttp for any production environments.

Oh OK, thanks for your return.
